# How to make images , iframes, icons stand beside texts without break

Tags: html, css, iframe, frontend

I've spent three hours trying to reproduce the image above, however I am unable to make the texts remain on the side and centered with facebook-pile and icons. Can anyone help me?

Code:

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<section class="social-media">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="fb-pile">
                                <h2> no Facebook:</h2>
                                <div class="fb-facepile" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/facebookdevelopers" data-max-rows="1" data-colorscheme="light" data-size="small" data-show-count="true"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="social-icons">
                                <h2>Compartilhar:</h2>
                                <a target="_blank" href="" title="Ir para página do facebook">
                                    <span class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></span>
                                </a>
                                <a target="_blank" href="" title="Ir para página do twitter">
                                    <span class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></span>
                                </a>
                                <a target="_blank" href="" title="Ir para página do instagram">
                                    <span class="fa fa-instagram fa-2x"></span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <div class="trip-advisor">
                                <img class="trip-advisor-img" title="Recomende o Pub Crawl no Trip Advisor" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/fr/1/1d/TripAdvisor-logo.png"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
```

Comment: It seems to be working for me, what's the issue?

Comment: is not working perfectly.. i need the icons and the facebook-pile beside and centered

Comment: That's how it's displaying for me unless the window is resized below one of your breakpoints, at which point they stack, which is the intended behavior of Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the `.social-media h2` style to include `display: inline-block` instead of floating it:

http://codepen.io/a_double/pen/EayaOa